# How to recreate subpixel anti-aliasing like Windows Command Prompt

Tags: vector, text, anti-aliasing

I want to be able to create a anti-aliasing effect as shown in windows command prompt with any text or vector I'd like without having to screenshot it within the program. How could I go about doing this?

[image: alt]

Comment: Vector or bitmap result? With a bitmap result, you will get a "fake" antialiasing, because the image won't 'know' how the pixels are aligned on a user's screen. With a vector image, you either don't have to do anything (as the local vector renderer will take care of it) or you get a fake result as well.

Comment: Do you want to recreate it pixel art style super big as shown?

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, using the free [LomoCopy LT Std Midi](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/b5f44235feb108e10b932277b02d4629) font:

[image: animation]

Over a black background type the text and use the Appearance Panel to add a light fill color with a lighten blend option:

[image]

Duplicate this fill, change the color and from the menu Effect → Distort Transform → Transform → move it horizontally to the left:

[image: horizontally left]

Duplicate this second fill, change the color and double click Transform → move it horizontally to the right:

[image: horizontally right]

Click each Fill Opacity at the Appearance Panel to change the blending modes and obtain different color effects.

End

[image: End]

Comment: Editing this to include how bending modes varied and were changed would be helpful.

Comment: I added a generic way of how to change blending modes since it would be different for each color and background, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a result exactly like your example but you could do like this in Illustrator:

1. Type text in 120pt size (white) over a black background.
2. Add a shadow from the Effects options with positive x-offset (2mm).
   Set Y-offset and blur to 0. Set the color to red and opacity 75%.
3. In the appearance panel, copy the shadow and edit x-offset to
   negative(-2mm). Set the color to blue and opacity 75%.
4. Add Rasterize from the Effects options. In this example I used 12ppi
   resolution with transparent background and no antialising.

[image]
Sorry for the swedish text in the UI, but I hope you can figure it out anyway.

Now the result can be a bit unpredictable with shadow not appearing on some letters so one need to tweek  and experiment.