# How do I create this text style with multiple offset fill colours in Illustrator please?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

How do I create this text style with multiple offset fill colours in Illustrator please?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/117027/120647

Comment: @Danielillo i don't think that it is duplicate at all. see my answer since in above image there is clear natural blending like our color wheel where blue+yellow= green and red+blue=purple so its just blended in multiply mode :)

Comment: I kind of feel it is a duplicate. While Danielilo *did* alter blending modes in the answer at the duplicate, that was not detailed int he answer itself. Perhaps editing to include the blending mode chances would help.

Answer (score 2):

**Its made by using `Multiply` Blending Option**

=> Make your font and fill it to blue color then go to `Appearance` and double Click on Opacity then change it's mode `Normal to Multiply`. do same for other 2 colors and then just adjust your Fonts :) and voila you got it!

=> basically even i wasn't sure about this before trying but i was damn clear that this looks same as our color wheel like `blue and yellow = Green` so that's where my idea became answer :)

[image]

Comment: My approach was *almost* exactly the same as yours, except... I used the appearance palette and added the new fills to the same single text element, applied transform effect to each new fill to get the correct x-y translations, and set each fill's opacity to multiply there - that way it's all *one single* ***easily-edited*** text string, but looks just right. also you can then save it as a graphic style and one-click apply it to other elements.